# 90s Tv show with magical items - in the end the dog gets sent to be the ruler instead of the baby

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is a TV I remember watching when I was young in the 90s in the UK.

There were lots of magic items that could do specific things. I remember the tooth paste made someone in the show start speaking different languages. In the TV show the kids were trying to collect all these magical items before some grown ups did and once they were all collected then a chosen one would take them all back somewhere (maybe the moon).

It might be that the grown-ups wanted to dump rubbish onto the moon and wanted to use the items to do it.

I remember an episode where a water container was found to be one of the items and so one of the magical characters put some tablets in to make the water never go down so that the container couldn't be taken.

I also remember at the end they realised that the baby in the family was the chosen one to go with the items but in the end the family dog went instead and was pictured looking happy on the moon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly *[The Miraculous Mellops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miraculous_Mellops_(TV_series))* (1991-1992).

Your description perfectly matches the plot of the first season:

> The Miraculous Mellops is an Australian sci-fi/comedy television series, created by Karl Zwicky and Margarita Tassone and produced by Film Australia and Millennium Pictures in association with the Network Ten. Aimed at children, the first season screened on Australian television in 1991 with the second season of the series screening in 1992.

> **The first season centred on the "Search for the Grand Baby" plot. An alien race of children exist on the moon, known as Moonlings. Their leader, The Grand Baby, is fast approaching the end of his life, and without an heir, it is decided that a great power will be sent to Earth to choose a new leader for the people there.** The power itself, consisting of all the psychic and magical abilities that the Grand Baby possessed, arrived on Earth but hit the Mellops' crystal punchbowl, "splitting" around the house, hitting several household items.
>
> **Suddenly, the Mellop teens start to notice the powers associated with the items.** For example; the T-Shirt of invisibility, the baseball cap of flight, the vacuum cleaner of time travel and even **the toothpaste of linguistic ability.**

> After all the powers are finally collected, and the Dumps have taken advantage of the Moonlings' flying Kombi, it seemed the Mellops had tried everyone in the household to find out if they were the new Grand Baby. To no avail, **after trying all the Mellops and Dumps family members, it is finally discovered that the new Grand Baby is none other than the Mellops' family dog, Ajax.**
>
> **Ajax is brought to the Moon, and hailed as the new leader.** After a tearful goodbye, Jane and Ralph go back to the Moon to educate Ajax on being a royal ruler. The Mellops prepare for a "normal life", but things don't stay quiet for long....