# TV show with a giant alien baby that ages backwards

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

There was a alien baby but they were huge. I think they were like a king or queen of mars or the moon. The baby aged backwards I think and they were really old. I think the baby was the antagonist or at least the "boss."

I don't think this was an American show it was maybe Canadian or a BBC show. I saw this in the 90s so the show is from the 70s 80s or early 90s. This was also a kid friendly show. Seemed like a scifi drama type deal.

Comment: When a baby ages backwards what does it turn into?

Comment: @OrganicMarble A ratings bomb.

Comment: A user with the same name as you tried to edit this question.  If that is you, you should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to regain control of the question.  That will allow you to edit it, comment on answers and accept the correct answer when it is posted.

Answer (score 11):

This is probably the fourth (and final) season of [Mork and Mindy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%26_Mindy) from 1982.

The alien visitor, Mork, played by Robin Williams, finally marries Mindy, played by Pam Dawber. [Mork lays an egg](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/lay-an-egg) which hatches into a "baby", [Mearth](https://morkandmindy.fandom.com/wiki/Mearth_McConnell), played by Jonathan Winters. Mearth appears to be a middle-aged man and ages backwards.

The show was soon cancelled. You may be remembering the baby as "antagonist " because of the character's outsized role in killing the show.

This seems to be a natural progression of such shows relying on sexual tension between a male and a female lead character: After awhile, the characters get together and this undermines the thing holding viewers' attention.

In the particular case of this show, it's possible the "baby aging backwards" gimmick was an attempt to stave this off, as newborn babies seemed to have killed off half a dozen sitcoms before.

Also, Jonathan Winters' style of humor may have clashed with the zany Robin Williams antics viewers had become used to.

Since "Mork and Mindy" was a spinoff of Happy Days", it's especially appropriate to describe this moment as "[Jumping the Shark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_the_shark)".

Comment: Interesting that u mention clash twixt Winters and Robin because afaik, it was RW's admiration for JW that contributed to JW being on the show -- I think Williams said that he was influenced by Winters. Two great comics now gone... oh, well.

Comment: @releseabe I wouldn't put it on Winters; the idea of the Mearth character just didn't fit.

Comment: Understood -- maybe having two funny guys in general has some challenges, maybe especially if they are not dissimilar in style. Like two magnets of the same pole. Most (all?) two-man comedy teams have the funny guy and of course the straight man.

Comment: @releseabe Which was Mindy's job. Now there's a third wheel.

Comment: It always seems to me that the injection of a new character is a sign of creative exhaustion... the writers ran out of story ideas for the existing cast and hoped a new character would fix it. Seems like it is always disruptive in a negative way.

Comment: @AnthonyX My thoughts exactly.

Comment: From what I've read, filming and editing *Mork and Mindy* was an extremely taxing exercise in trying to make sense of Robin Williams' drug fueled antics.  Basically, "film a bunch of crazy shit and try to edit it into a coherent story."  Williams did some really funny comedy stuff, but was from all accounts was really hard to keep on track.

Comment: Another Orkan character in a few episodes was the Orkan Eldar who, since Orkans age backwards, was portrayed by a child, Vidal Peterson, a casting choice which turned out to be rather appropriate..

Comment: This was my first thought from the title, but I don't think it matches certain details. I wouldn't classify Jonathan Winters' Mearth as "huge" (though he was overweight). It actually reminds me more of part of a more recent kids' show Ben & Holly's Little Kingdom where they had "huge" (relative to the tiny fairies and elves) baby aliens that shrunk to small (even relatively speaking) older aliens, but that seems too cartoonish for what I think OP is looking for. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE-izNayzws

Comment: @BenHocking I guess until we hear from OP we'll never know.

Answer (score 3):

It might be [The Miraculous Mellops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miraculous_Mellops_(TV_series)), an Australian children's sci-fi comedy series from 1991. More detail can be seen in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247087/90s-tv-show-with-magical-items-in-the-end-the-dog-gets-sent-to-be-the-ruler-in/247092#247092) to a previous question, but the show does feature a "Grand Baby" who is the leader of a race of inhabitants of the moon. I don't believe the Grand Baby aged backwards, but he was reaching the end of his life and the main plot of the first season of the show was about the search for his replacement.

Answer (score -1):

The whole aging backwards seems to be quite common.  There was a show in the early 1990s on BBC1 on Saturday mornings called Parallel 9 [(Youtube of the intro)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXgH-8hQT-s) where a young "Time Baron" (played by an older man) is sentenced to something along the lines of only being allowed to be awake for 2 hours every Saturday.  His species aged backwards and he was one of the hosts of the show.

Comment: Did he appear as a giant?  Was he an alien?  King of Mars or the Moon?  Does this match the question at all except for the age backward bit?

Comment: While I don't recall the character appearing as a giant, I believe he was supposed to be an alien prince.  This was also a BBC show in the early 90s as suggested in the original question.